# convert string representation of list to python list

Tags: python

I have ran the function in main class like:

```
def get_tote_task_ttp_list_not_complete(self, butler_host):
    try:
        server_ip = coreApi._env_details['BUTLER_SERVER']
    except TypeError:  # TypeError is raised when we fetch data from None
        server_ip = butler_host

    obj = ErlangArg(server_ip)
    out = obj.erl_multiple_arg('tote_task', 'search_by', ["[{status, notequal, complete}],[task_key,tote_id]"])
    status = out.lstrip('{ok,').rstrip('}').strip('""')
    return status`
```

mainclass:

```
jai = gmc.get_tote_task_ttp_list_not_complete("172.29.2.54")
    print(jai)
    print(type(jai))`
```

whose output is:

```
[[<<"a29c4601-68a1-40e3-b986-50c8ec65bf18">>,<<"TOTE1">>],
     [<<"03a89100-18cb-4f06-821b-b368b86f8829">>,<<"TOTE2">>],
     [<<"8897a38e-cfaf-4983-afc2-fcdcaf7ef59d">>,<<"TOTE10">>]]`

<class 'str'>
```

and I need to convert this to list so output should be like:

```
[<<"a29c4601-68a1-40e3-b986-50c8ec65bf18">>,<<"TOTE1">>],[<<"03a89100-18cb-4f06-821b-b368b86f8829">>,<<"TOTE2">>],[<<"8897a38e-cfaf-4983-afc2-fcdcaf7ef59d">>,<<"TOTE10">>]
```

```
import ast

def get_tote_task_ttp_list_not_complete(self, butler_host):
    try:
        server_ip = coreApi._env_details['BUTLER_SERVER']
    except TypeError:  # TypeError is raised when we fetch data from None
        server_ip = butler_host

    obj = ErlangArg(server_ip)
    out = obj.erl_multiple_arg('tote_task', 'search_by', ["[{status, notequal, complete}],[task_key,tote_id]"])
    status = out.lstrip('{ok,').rstrip('}').strip('""')

    # Convert status string to list
    status_list = ast.literal_eval(status)

    return status_list
```

But getting the following error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [[<<"a29c4601-68a1-40e3-b986-50c8ec65bf18">>,<<"TOTE1">>],
      ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

Comment: Do you want to use a specific library to do the conversion?

Comment: `<<"asdf">>` is not value python.  However, do you want a list of strings more like `"<<\"asdf\">>"`?

Comment: Yes fetching this info in erlang: tote_task:search_by([{status,notequal,complete}],[task_key,tote_id]). Output:
{ok,[[<<"a29c4601-68a1-40e3-b986-50c8ec65bf18">>,
      <<"TOTE1">>],
     [<<"03a89100-18cb-4f06-821b-b368b86f8829">>,<<"TOTE2">>],
     [<<"8897a38e-cfaf-4983-afc2-fcdcaf7ef59d">>,<<"TOTE10">>]]}

Comment: Got the solution: status = status.replace("<<", "")
        status = status.replace(">>", "")
        status = eval(status)
        return status

Comment: @JaideepKaushik Cool, if that works then you might replace `eval(status)` with `ast.literal_eval(status)` as it is a little safer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import re
string_list = '[[<<"a29c4601-68a1-40e3-b986-50c8ec65bf18">>,<<"TOTE1">>],[<<"03a89100-18cb-4f06-821b-b368b86f8829">>,<<"TOTE2">>],[<<"8897a38e-cfaf-4983-afc2-fcdcaf7ef59d">>,<<"TOTE10">>]]'
print(type(string_list))
print(string_list)

# Extract the values between << and >>
values = re.findall('<<([^<>]+)>>', string_list)

# Split the extracted values into separate lists
native_list = [values[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(values), 2)]
print("\n------------ Convert in to list---------------\n")
print(native_list)
print(type(native_list))
```

## Terminal Output

[image]